# Command+F not working on Mac across all applications

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Every once in a while, my Mac will do this thing where <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will no longer work to find/search in any application I use (Atom, Slack, Chrome, etc). <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> still works in Chrome for "Find Next" as does <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Atom. The problem seems to be solely limited to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. It doesn't matter which <kbd>Command</kbd> key I use (left/right/built-in/external). When I pull up the Keyboard Viewer, the <kbd>Command</kbd> keypress registers correctly but not the <kbd>F</kbd>

**Things I have tried:**

- Closing all applications
- Fully restarting. The problem persists across full restarts.
- Resetting all keyboard settings to default
- Uninstalling Karabiner (which I use for a couple of shortcuts unrelated to <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)

The problem persists after trying all of the above and usually goes away after a couple of days for seemingly no reason. Has anyone run into this before or can anyone help me diagnose the issue further? This is driving me nuts.

*OS Details:* Macbook Pro running OS X El Capitan v 10.11.6

Comment: I have since upgraded to High Sierra 10.13.1 and it started happening again this morning.

Comment: Sanity check, first. When this problem is happening, can you verify that your [keys are still being registered as pressed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40192/how-can-i-tell-exactly-what-keys-are-being-pressed-on-the-mac)? Eliminating the hardware as a concern.

Comment: The `Command` registers as being pressed but not the `F`. When I press `Command` + `Shift` + `F` the `F` is registered. So something low-level seems to be stopping that from being picked up in the `Command`+`F` case.

Comment: does this happen with both `Command` keys? Does it happen with an external keyboard's `Command` keys?

Comment: Yes it happens with both command keys as well as external keyboard's command keys.

Comment: I am seeing this on 10.12.6 also. Very annoying. Eventually (weeks later) it seems to fix itself. But then here it is again....

Comment: Also in 10.13.6

Comment: I get the same thing although it only affects Chrome.

Comment: I get the same thing but only with an external keyboard. Anyone find a solution (other than waiting)?

Answer (score 11):

This has been driving me nuts for months too, and today I figured out that when I press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (in that order), the <kbd>F</kbd> key press doesn't register. However, if I flip the order by pressing <kbd>F</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd>, it works again. That seems to "reset" something so that I'm able to continue using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for the rest of that session. I hope this helps!

Comment: This started happening to me again this morning. `F`+`Command` does seem to work to search! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have the same "reset" behavior for me. I am only able to get it to work with `F`+`Command`.

Answer (score 3):

this is old post but it is first in the google search results by "cmd F doesn't work", so let me post a link to working solution

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5471806

TL;DR

1. remove `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db`
2. restart in safe mode
3. restart again in normal mode
4. PROFIT

and i'm not sure about deleting file, please someone check it

Comment: deleting the cache file is not needed for me. It seems starting the safe mode is the only solution for me.